# Vue - Unable pass specific value to higher component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props, vue-data

I am getting the following - Cannot read property 'free' of undefined.

I will be adding this button component on multiple pages and I have data object which will allow me to add text based on whatever page I want displayed on a page. For example if its on the homepage I would like to use `<buttons :text="buttonText.free" />` and on about us page I would like to use `<buttons :text="buttonText.spend" />`

Template file

```
<template>
  <main class="container">
    <buttons :text="buttonText.free" />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import Buttons from '~/components/atoms/buttons.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Buttons
  }
}
</script>
```

Component file

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="button"">
      <span>{{ buttonText }}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    text: String
  },
  data () {
    return {
      buttonText: {
        free: 'free',
        spend: 'spend',
        now: 'now',
        nowFree: 'now free'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should define your data in your parent component's `data` property. All the variables that is used inside the `template` tag will be fetched from `data`, `computed` or `props` of the component. You are passing an `undefined` buttonText data to your `buttons` component.

```
<template>
  <main class="container">
    <buttons :text="buttonText.free" />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import Buttons from '~/components/atoms/buttons.vue'

export default {
data() {
  return {
    buttonText: {
        free: 'free',
        spend: 'spend',
        now: 'now',
        nowFree: 'now free'
      }
  }
},
  components: {
    Buttons
  }
}
</script>
```

and in your `buttons` component, just accept the props passed by the parent component. In this case, you are using `text` as the props of the `buttons` component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="button"">
      <span>{{ text }}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    text: String
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

template.vue

```
<template>
  <main class="container">
    <buttons :text="your customized text" />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import Buttons from '~/components/atoms/buttons.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Buttons
  }
}
</script>
```

buttons.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button class="button">
      <span>{{ text }}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    text: String
  }
}
</script>
```

here is a simple solution to solve your problem
but you need to learn more fundamentals on vue components
[vue component doc](https://cn.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)